# New repeater items disappear in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp:repeater that im populating via updatepanel (its inside updatepanel) and I can add new rows to it fine. But when I submit the repeater.items is empty.

However if I remove the updatepanel and just bind the results manually I can see the repeater.items fine on submit in code-behind. Is my code-behind not seeing the changes?

C

Comment: Please, share some code (html, cs, vb, js), for a better understanding of your problem. Also, most people will recommend you to avoid UpdatePanel.

Comment: Here I assume that you added new item to repeater, and do you want to save those items to database? If so, I prefer you create one datatable, add all items to datatable, bind that datatable to repeater. Also whenever you add new item to datatable, store that datatable in viewstate. So when you postback page, you will have your datatable stored in viewstate, so get it from there and save items in datatbase. Hope you understand. Please let me know if you want example.